# find element with highest value with XPath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<div class="box box-0 box-hover-null">10828</div>
```

I have a series of these in an html document, with variable number as text().

I need to find the first div with the highest and lowest text value.

my current selector:

```
//div[string-length(text()) > 0 and contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' box-0 ')]
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please add a tag for it. Also please add several examples of the HTML. You are trying to get all of these numbers and find the highest and lowest number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <div class="box box-0 box-hover-null">10828</div>
> ```
>
> I have a series of these in an html document, with variable number as
>   text().
>
> I need to find the first div with the highest and lowest text value.

As far as I know, Selenium uses the XPath engine of the respective browser -- at present all browsers only support XPath 1.0.

Thus, what is required is an XPath 1.0 expression selecting the first `<div>` element whose string value is castable to number and this number is the minimum of all such `<div>` numeric values.

A similar XPath expression is required but that selects the first such `<div>` element with maximum numeric value.

Here are such two XPath expressions that select the wanted `<div>` elements:

**1st `<div>` element with minimum numeric value**:

```
(//div[number(.) = number(.)
     and number(.) = //div[number(.) = number(.)
                         and not(number(.) > //div[number(.) = number(.)]/text())
                          ]
      ]
)[1]
```

**1st `<div>` element with maximum numeric value**:

```
(//div[number(.) = number(.)
     and number(.) = //div[number(.) = number(.)
                         and not(number(.) < //div[number(.) = number(.)]/text())
                          ]
      ]
)[1]
```

**Here is an XSLT 1.0 -- based verification**. The transformation below evaluates these two XPath expressions against an XML document and copies to the output the results of this evaluation (the selected nodes):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    First node with Minimum value: <xsl:copy-of select=
    "(//div[number(.) = number(.)
    and number(.) = //div[number(.) = number(.)
                        and not(number(.) > //div[number(.) = number(.)]/text())
                         ]
           ]
      )[1]"/>

=======================

    First node with Maximum value: <xsl:copy-of select=
    "(//div[number(.) = number(.)
    and number(.) = //div[number(.) = number(.)
                        and not(number(.) &lt; //div[number(.) = number(.)]/text())
                         ]
           ]
      )[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<html>
  <div class="box box-0 box-hover-null">100</div>
  <div class="box box-1 box-hover-null">100</div>
  <div class="box box-2 box-hover-null">0500</div>
  <div class="box box-3 box-hover-null">00500</div>
  <div class="box box-4 box-hover-null">300</div>
  <div class="box box-5 box-hover-null">200</div>
</html>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
    First node with Minimum value: <div class="box box-0 box-hover-null">100</div>

=======================

    First node with Maximum value: <div class="box box-2 box-hover-null">0500</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the max

```
max(//div[@class='box box-0 box-hover-null'])
```

you can get the element using

```
(//div[.=max(//div[@class='box box-0 box-hover-null'])][[@class='box box-0 box-hover-null'])[1]
```

For min value

```
min(//div[@class='box box-0 box-hover-null'])
```

You can get the element using

```
(//div[.=min(//div[@class='box box-0 box-hover-null'])][[@class='box box-0 box-hover-null'])[1]
```

Comment: thanks, I tried to match something but I couldn't. I'm also trying to use selenium instead of testing the xpath via chrome if that helps

Comment: can you please the script that you tried. BTW which language you are using.